# Getting SQLException errors in connection pool

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am getting a Oracle JDBC connection from a connection pool using a data source object.
And using the connection to insert some logs into DB from java (via java static method).
Since there will be around 10 to 20 inserts per user, what I am doing is, I am commiting the connection at request level in Filter and closing the connection at session level (via Session Listener's sessionDestroyed() method)
I did not get any error in testing but in production environment, I am getting few error as follows,

```
java.sql.SQLException: execute, Exception = null (one scenario)
java.sql.SQLException: close, Exception = null (for another scenario)
```

How to avoid these errors? Can I instead commit and close the connection in java static method, instead of commiting at request level and closing at session level?

But what amuses me is that, those errors are occuring inspite of having the below logic in my java static method,

```
if (con.isClosed() || con == null) {
 DBConnectionHelper connHelper = DBConnectionHelper.createInstance();
    con=connHelper.getConnection("ds");
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
}
```

So I am checking for the above, and so there is no way connection can be closed when I am trying for execute, am I right?
But not sure and confused why its occuring.

Comment: Why would you close the connection in a connection pool?  Also, in your if, I would check to see if con was null first before the con.isClosed().

Comment: @Mike: Some connection pools intercept the `close()` call and instead return the connection to the pool.

Comment: @skaffman - Well, before a first connection, what does `con` point to?

Comment: @Mike If you use a connection pool, then you do need to close the connection: that is the signal for the connection pool that it is available for re-use. You (normally) don't get the actual connection, but a proxy which is managed by the connection pool (and as skaffman says: intercepts the close).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your con object is null?

Consider the following block:

```
if (con.isClosed() || con == null) {
 DBConnectionHelper connHelper = DBConnectionHelper.createInstance();
    con=connHelper.getConnection("ds");
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
}
```

First you ask if the connection is closed. Then you see if its null. If con really is null, you will get a NullpointerException.

Switch the checks and see if it helps anything :-)

```
if (con == null || con.isClosed()) {
 DBConnectionHelper connHelper = DBConnectionHelper.createInstance();
    con=connHelper.getConnection("ds");
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
}
```

Comment: Fine let me change that and see. And should I manually close the connection pool object as and when in static java method or close it once at last( as I do in sessionDestroyed() method in session Listener) ?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if (con.isClosed() || con == null) {
```

To

```
if ( con == null || con.isClosed() ) {
```

And see if there is a difference.

How did you check `con=connHelper.getConnection("ds");` as a success?
I fear `con` is `null` before executing `con.setAutoCommit(false);`
If that is the case, you need to check if connection string for production db is correct.

Comment: Fine let me change that and see. And should I manually close the connection pool object as and when in static java method or close it once at last( as I do in sessionDestroyed() method in session Listener) ?